# Error when playing notification sound without user interaction on modern browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-audio

In my reactjs app I am playing an audio when receiving a websocket message:

```
  const playSound = () => {
    if (audioRef.current) {
      audioRef.current
        .play()
        .then(() => {})
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error("Audio playback error:", error);
        });
    }
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    const element = document.getElementById("audioButton");
    if (element) {
      element.click();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("receive_message", (data) => {
      if (data && data.action === "play_sound") {
        handleClick();
      }
      fetchOrders();
    });

    return () => {
      socket.off("receive_message");
    };
  }, []);
```

```
      <audio ref={audioRef}>
        <source src="/audio/sound.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
      </audio>
      <button
        id="audioButton"
        style={{ display: "none" }}
        onClick={() => playSound()}
      />
```

When the user is interacting with the website the audio plays correctly, but when the user is in another tab or did not interact with the website for a while, this error is being thrown (edge, chrome, latest versions):

```
Audio playback error: DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.
```

In Firefox:

```
Audio playback error: DOMException: The play method is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.
```

I know that modern browsers prevent audios from being played automatically but since I am working on a chat application with a user notification feature, I am looking for a workaround.

The reason why I am triggering a click event when receiving a websocket message instead of directly playing the audio is to simulate a user interaction, but this does not fix the issue.

I know there are similiar questions but none of them provides a working solution for this issue.
Is there any way to bypass this?

I tried to simulate a user interaction with a click event instead of playing the audio directly which did not solve the issue.

Comment: Are you doing this so that when you get a chat message, and say the user is doing something else you want them to know a new message has appeared?

Comment: @Keith Yes. I've seen that feature in chat apps like Tidio. When users are in another tab, they get notified that a message has arrived. Drastically improves UX imo

Comment: Then I would use the Notification API, that's what it's designed for.  More info here ->  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API

Comment: If it was that easy to bypass it, it would be pointless. Use the notification API or enable audio for the website (in the browsers settings for each website)

Comment: @Keith thanks for the advice. Since only the admins of the website are using the chat I will definitely consider that.

However, if I wanted to notify customers, I would still prefer a sound over a notification since I made the experience that users mostly do not allow notifications.